# protection in v8 of google app script fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code which was working ok till I have allowed the google app script to upgrade to v8.
This code is used for adding another user programatically.

```
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.addEditor(eMailID);
```

in v8 it gives me the following error.

```
[20-06-01 06:12:16:027 IST] Exception: The parameters (number[]) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Protection.addEditor.
at EnableShare(EnableAccess:51:18)
```

Important observation is that when I disable the runtime v8 and switch to the earlier version, code gets executed without any error and the spreadsheet adds the eMailID as another editor.

Any corrections in the syntax in the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

From your explanation, in your script, if `eMailID` is an array, I think that when V8 is enabled, such error occurs. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
protection.addEditor(eMailID);
```

#### To:

```
protection.addEditor(eMailID[0]);
```

or

```
protection.addEditors(eMailID);
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `eMailID` is an array like `["###email address###"]`.

#### References:

- [addEditor(user)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addeditoruser)
- [addEditors(emailAddresses)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addeditorsemailaddresses)

Comment: Is there any tool which can analyze the version changes and suggest the syntax changes at the least.